# How to find a web control inside the AjaxControlToolKit TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontrol

I am working on dynamic generation of WebControls. I Have a Ajax TabContainer with a TabPanel inside it. The TabPanel contains a ContentTemplate. Inside the ContentTemplate is a Asp:Panel.

'Current Issue: I am trying to add my dynamically generated web controls inside the Asp:Panel present inside the ContentTemplate. But i couldn't add the dynamic controls directly and also couldn't find the asp Panel as it is always `null` and

> Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object

How to solve this issue?

My aspx Code:

```
<ajaxControlToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<ajaxControlToolKit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width ="1178px" VerticalStripWidth="1000px" OnDemand="false" ScrollBars="Vertical" ActiveTabIndex="1" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true">
   <ajaxControlToolKit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat ="server">    
      <HeaderTemplate> Upload</HeaderTemplate>
          <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Panel ID ="Panel1" runat="server">
              </asp:Panel>
          </ContentTemplate>       
   </ajaxControlToolKit:TabPanel>         
</ajaxControlToolKit:TabContainer>
```

My C# code:

```
protected void findpanel()
{
    Panel Panel1= TabContainer1.FindControl("TabPanel1").FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
    **//Alwals Null**
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "TB1";
    tb.Text = "Hi";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    **//Object reference not set to an instance of an oject**         
}

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    findpanel();
}
```

Comment: are you using the master page in your project ? if yes, is it a nested master page or is just one ?

Comment: @AliShahrokhi I am not using any Master Page in my VS12 solution. Just webform pages

Comment: try to put findpanel(); on Page_Init or Page_load to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to put ur findpanel() at Page_init or Page_load.